# Issue with stimul soft report in margin left

Tags: asp.net, reporting, stimulsoft

I use *Stimul soft 2013* for reporting in ASP .NET. 
When I show my report in *A5 letter*, it shows like this:
[image]

My text from left did not show correctly. I suppose if I could add margin from left to my text, it will solve my problem.

Consider that, I added html tag `justify` to my text
any body.

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Cold you attach a report template file?

Answer (score 0):

In Stimul you can shrink your text.

For this problem is better that you set Shrink Text to "True", set a Minimum Size for it, and set Word Wrap to "True".

And sometimes you must put an empty text box to fix it.